# Selecting items in a dropdown widget with VBA and SeleniumBasic

Tags: html, vba, selenium

I have been automating downloads from our data provider using SeleniumBasic and VBA. Everything was running just fine until they made a change in the design of their download form (the price you pay for scraping someone elses' web site).

The new download form now has this widget:
[image]

While is looks like "All" will be selected by default, I'd like to confirm that each time I run my download by expanding the widget and clicking the "All" button.

The HTML for the table row is this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="table_text1" width="2%" nowrap="" valign="top">Appointment Status </td>
  <td id="apt_status_td">
    <select id="apt_status" name="apt_status[]" multiple="multiple" class="filterSelections" style="display: none; visibility: visible;">
      <option value="2870" selected="" aria-selected="true">Scheduled</option>
      <option value="2871" selected="" aria-selected="true">Confirmed</option>
      <option value="2872" selected="" aria-selected="true">Complete</option>
      <option value="2873" selected="" aria-selected="true">Rescheduled</option>
      <option value="4107" selected="" aria-selected="true">Same Day Cancellation</option>
      <option value="2874" selected="" aria-selected="true">Cancelled</option>
      <option value="2875" selected="" aria-selected="true">No Show</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" style="width: 263px;">
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span>
      <span>7 of 7 selected</span>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am able to identify the widget with this:

```
Dim el As Selenium.WebElement
text = "apt_status"
With this.Driver
  Set el = .FindElementById(text)
```

but

```
  el.Click
```

Gives me an error #11:

> ElementNotVisibleError
>   element not visible
>     (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (--a bunch of hex--),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

I get the same `ElementNotVisibleError` when I tried both of these as well:

```
Set el = .FindElementByClass("ui-corner-all")
Set el = .FindElementByClass("ui-multiselect-all")
```

Just before posting this, it occurred to me to try this, as well:

```
text = "apt_status"
Dim els As WebElements
With this.Driver
  Set els = .FindElementsById(text)
  For Each el In els
    el.AsSelect.SelectByIndex (2870)
  Next
```

but that yields error code 7:

> NoSuchElementError
>   Cannot locate option with index: 2870

on the line `el.AsSelect.SelectByIndex (2870)`

So, it appears to me that I'm on the right track for clicking the drop down, but

- How do I make the element `Visible` so that it can be clicked?
- How do I find the "All" button to click it?

  - I would prefer to do this because I have to log in to the page for different clients and they will have different options to select.

Comment: An alternative approach could be iterating the aria-selected elements of each option to see if it is set to true. You should be able to flip them to true, if they are false. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304092(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I will definitely look into that, @RyanWildry. I'm just not sure if I'll actually be able to get to them since it's consistently giving me the `ElementNotVisibleError` every time I try to access anything in that widget. (Another project is temporarily higher priority, so it'll probably be a few days... :( Grrrr)

Comment: Selenium is great, but if it's not working try plain jane IE. Or, better still use jQuery with ExecScript if possible.